# Files from res file to sdcard on android

Tags: android, file, sd-card

Hi I'm trying to get files in my res/raw folder of my android application to be copied onto the phone's sdcard so they can be set as ringtones. Here is what I have so far on my application:

```
package com.wochstudios.ringtonetest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.*;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.res.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class setRingtone extends Activity {
Button setBtn;
TextView result;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    setBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Attempt to make file out on raw element
            setRing();
        }
    });
}
public void setRing(){
    File newSoundFile = new File("/sdcard/media/ringtone", "fortkickass.mp3");
    Uri mUri =          Uri.parse("android.resource://com.wochstudios.ringtonetest/R.raw.fortkickass");

    ContentResolver mCr = getContentResolver();

    AssetFileDescriptor soundFile;

    try {
           soundFile= mCr.openAssetFileDescriptor(mUri, "r");
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           soundFile=null;   
       }


       try {
          byte[] readData = new byte[1024];
          FileInputStream fis = soundFile.createInputStream();
          FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newSoundFile);
          int i = fis.read(readData);

          while (i != -1) {
            fos.write(readData, 0, i);
            i = fis.read(readData);
          }

          fos.close();
       } catch (IOException io) {
       }





}
```

}

this crashes once it hits the second try catch of the setRing method, i got this code from a question posted earlier but i can't find the link anymore any help would be great

EDIT

i fooled around and discovered that the Assetfiledescriptor soundFile is null so that what causes the crash so now i need to figure out why it is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Explanation:

The first try/catch block does:

```
soundFile=null;
```

if the read fails.

Then, in the second, you use soundfile in:

```
FileInputStream fis = soundFile.createInputStream();
```

You are reading null because the first try failed

## Edit:

Use this instead

```
InputStream ins = context.getResources().openRawResource (R.raw.FILENAME)
byte[] buffer = new byte[ins.available()];
ins.read(buffer);
ins.close();
String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+File.separator+FILENAME;
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
fos.write(buffer);
fos.close();
```

Comment: I get the IOexception @ALeadam
'    try {
         InputStream ins = this.getResources().openRawResource (R.raw.fortkickass);
         byte[] buffer = new byte[ins.available()];
         ins.read(buffer);
         ins.close();
         String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+File.separator+"fortkickass.mp3";
         result.setText(filename);
         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
         fos.write(buffer);
         fos.close();
        
          
        } catch (IOException io) {
         result.setText("nope");
        }'

Comment: @BeardFace where you get the exception?

Comment: im not entirely sure i think its with the FileOutputStream because when i commented that out i don't get it any more @ALeaadam

Comment: @BeardFace you should be able to write to the sdcard. What did you use as FILENAME?

Comment: @Aleadam i put fortkickass.mp3 cause thats what it's called in my raw folder, Do i need any permissions to write to the sdcard?

Comment: Do you have your SD card mounted? Do you have android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in your manifest?

Comment: just turned on the permission i think that did the trick i don't get the error any more, Thanks for all your help @Aleadam

Answer (score 1):

Did you forget to set up permission to write in your Manifest file?

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```